# Why is $\int_0^1e^{e^x}dx$ equal to $\int_1^e{e^uu^{-1}}du$?

Tags: calculus, integration, change-of-variable

Why is this equality $\displaystyle\int_0^1e^{e^x}dx=\int_1^e{e^uu^{-1}}du$?

I don't see the change of variable that was used to pass from one integral to the other?

Could someone please explain?

And how to solve the latter?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$u\mapsto e^x$. This change of variable can be seen pretty easily from the bounds of integration and the integrand itself. $$\begin{bmatrix}u\\\mathrm du\end{bmatrix}\mapsto\begin{bmatrix}e^x\\e^x\mathrm dx\end{bmatrix}$$ Notice that $\mathrm du=e^x\mathrm dx$ is equivalent to saying $\mathrm du/u=\mathrm dx$. $$\int_{0}^{1}e^{e^x}\mathrm dx=\int_{1}^{e}e^u\cdot\mathrm du/u$$
This is a special integral and has a name, it is the exponential integral denoted $\mathrm {Ei}(x)$. The definite integral can be approximated, and doing so gives $6.316563839027679$.

Comment: Thank you so much Paras :) .You are younger than me and definitely better than me..

Comment: Thank you for your kind words and you're most welcome. :))

Answer (score 2):

The change of variables is $u = e^x$. Notice that $du = e^x dx = u dx $

Therefore,

$$ \int\limits_{u(0)}^{u(1)} e^{u} \cdot \frac{1}{u} du = \int\limits_1^e e^u u^{-1} du $$